# Documentation made Hyperlink editor function slow

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, markdown, hyperlinks

Since the introduction of Documentation, the standard Markdown editor dialog, 
**Hyperlink**, has changed, allowing to search for documentation links.

However, this change made the dialog slow to load: it can take what feels like up to a second (and it's highly variable) for the link input field to appear and get focus AFTER the UI dialog pops up.

### This affects the whole of SO, not just Documentation!

[image]
(a few hundred ms later)
[image]

Therefore, the following flow is disrupted:

1. Type the link text
2. Select link text
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or click the icon
4. Paste hyperlink with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
5. Confirm

Because of the (variable, potentially long) pause, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> before the input field is focused **overwrites the original selection in the editor**.

If you then proceed to paste again in the input field and confirm, then the blunder is fixed (the dialog somehow remembers the original selected text, even if it isn't exposed in UI).

If you back out, however, the accidental overwrite is not undone. All hail the undo button.

**Proposed resolution:** make sure that opening the popup guarantees that there is an input field that is focused. It's fine if the rest of the UI takes a bit of time to load, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> should not affect the text after the modal window visibly appears.

---

Additional testing shows that it's mainly the result of slow server response for AJAX requests

```
https://stackoverflow.com/render/insert-link?_=(number)
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/render/insert-link?_=(number)
```

Time To First Byte after request is sent is consistently over 100ms, spiking to 400ms and above.

**Update:** Strong evidence that the request delay is caused by AdBlock Plus. However, it's still questionable that this part of the interface needs to be loaded over AJAX.

Comment: Hmm. There shouldn't be anything in there that delays the load. Investigating.

Comment: @AdamLear I'm seeing ~300-400ms, sometimes more, for the AJAX call `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/render/insert-link?_=(number)` to start serving data. [Timing in Chrome](http://i.imgur.com/601HYnf.png)

Comment: I can confirm this problem. It now takes 2-3 seconds on my system (that I have a high network latency could be involved). Prior to yesterday it was so fast that it was not possible to paste to the underlying text field, with Crtl + L, Ctrl + V (the current delay makes it really irritating; it replaces what ever text is selected in the text field).

Comment: Yeah, FWIW I'm on a gigabit university link right now, so the actual request / transfer phases are negligible compared to the time the server spends to start serving content.

Comment: Interesting. It's nearly instant here (around 11ms). How long does the same request take here on MSO for you?

Comment: Same (in fact, that screenshot is for MSO, I think), despite no documentation tab. But it definitely started when Documentation went live. Accessing from Switzerland via HTTPS.

Comment: @Adam Lear: Trying it now on this very post, it is somewhat faster, but still 1-2 seconds. But it is also faster now on Stack Overflow proper (tried on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513189), essentially the same as here, 1-2 seconds.

Comment: @Adam Lear: I tried it on a Windows system and a Linux system. For both it was with the recent version Firefox, 47.0.1 and two NAT routers in front of the ISP (entirely different router for the first router for the two systems). Ping times to a local university's web server was approx. 100 ms.

Comment: More accurate timing for (my system) is 1.3 seconds from Ctrl + L is pressed until the link dialog appears.

Comment: @Adam Lear: I don't if it will be of any use, but I have posted [a traceroute to Meta Stack Overflow](http://pmortensen.eu/2/Traceroute_to_Meta_Stack_Overflow_2016-07-22T212917.html).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Does the "insert image" dialog take a similar amount of time?

Comment: @AdamLear Similar (100~400), but only once per editing session - subsequent attempts to show do not hit network. Every attempt at opening the link dialog hits network.

Comment: @Adam Lear: No, Ctrl + G is immediate after the initial use of it (it took 2-3 seconds the first time; for Ctrl + L I have observed a time of ca. 7 seconds the first time and 1-2 seconds thereafter). First time = after restart of Firefox. I got the same behavior on both Windows and Linux ([Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29)).

Comment: @Adam Lear: Correction: It is in fact per editing session, as for *Xan* (but it is still immediate if it the *same* post is *immediately* edited again - edit, Ctrl + G, Cancel, edit, Ctrl + G is immediate the second time even though a new edit session is started (on the same post)).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Could you please go to Network tools (Ctrl+Shift+Q), open the dialog with Ctrl+L, then highlight `insert-link` in the left-side list, switch the right-side panel to "Timings" and take a screenshot of that?

Comment: At Xan: It is now at [http://i.stack.imgur.com/eGeUz.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eGeUz.png) (the original view is at [http://i.stack.imgur.com/LPa73.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LPa73.png)).

Comment: What are your normal page load timings when you just browse the site? Say, for the home page or a question page?

Comment: @Adam I'm afraid I'm off for the night here, will measure tomorrow.

Comment: No worries. I'm trying to think of a workaround here... if your connection to us is normally slow, this is gonna be a bad time for sure. :/

Comment: @Adam Lear: Opening a question from http://stackoverflow.com/ took 3.5 seconds in the first instance and 2.1 seconds and 1.95 seconds for two subsequent questions. The initial longer time could be due to the 3G router falling back to [UMTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMTS_(telecommunication)) when idle or near idle for some time. And using the highest-performing mode, [HSDPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Speed_Packet_Access), when required. The (local) ping times are approx. 230 ms and 100 ms, respectively.

Comment: @Adam Lear: Just to be clear: On e.g. Server Fault there isn't any delay using Ctrl + L, not even the first time after launching Firefox.

Comment: @PeterMortensen New dialog is only enabled on SO and MSO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, it took forever because I'm a jackass and forgot about it... but the good news is this should be fixed now.

I originally made a number of assumptions (such as "nobody uses the dialog much anyway, right?" and "it's pretty straightforward, how long could it possibly take to load?") that clearly didn't hold true, so a few lessons were learned.

Again, apologies for the delay in fixing. Let me know if things are still wonky.

Comment: Now it feels fantastic. Thank you!